# Azure DSVM: balck screen when launched

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-dsvm

I have just deployed an Azure DSVM. However, when I connect to it, I just have a black screen.

Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: You could try reprovisioning or rehosting.  Other option would be to enable the boot diagnostics and see if it is stuck somewhere.

Comment: How long time did the VM show a black screen after RDP it? Also try to go to Azure portal > your VM > Boot diagnostics to watch a screenshot of your VM.

Comment: I have tried rehosting, it doesn't work. And the black screen never go off. I will try the boot diagnostic. I have also found some posts on internet explaining that it could be a slow connexion problem, I don't really understand the problem (I am totally new in this area), but maybe this is the problem...

Answer (score -1):

it looks like firewall issues, try this on the VM, edit local group policy as follow:

Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Connections

Find the RDP Transport policy and make it TCP only. It defaults to TCP and UDP.

Once changed, restart the server. Then test